# Let $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $\gcd (a,b)=1$, then $\gcd (ac,b)= \gcd(b,c)$.

Tags: number-theory

Problem: Let $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $\gcd (a,b)=1$, then $\gcd (ac,b)= gcd(b,c)$

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there exists $s,t \in\mathbb{Z}$ st $as+bt=1$
And then would I also have $cam+bn=bq+cr$?

Comment: Note that $c = cas+ cbt$.

Comment: Think about the greatest common divisor as the greatest common factor. If $a$ and $b$ have no common factor, from where comes the common factors between $ac$ and $b$?

Comment: It's also useful to notice that if $d \mid ac$ and $d \nmid a$, then $d \mid c$.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza Is the common factor just one?

Comment: @ematth7 There can be a lot of common factors, but only one can be the greatest. That's at least poetical.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza $d \mid ac$ and$ d∤ad∤a$, then $d∣c$ is only true if $d$ is a prime. A counterexample is $10 | 5 \cdot 6$

Comment: @Ovi yes, you are correct! I didn't payed attention to this. The conclusion is also valid if $\gcd(d, a) = 1$, which is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

If a number $k$ divides $b$ and $c$, then it trivially divides $ac$ and $b$. Conversely, if $j$ divides $ac$ and $b$, then $j$ must divide $c$ since $gcd(a,b)=1$. Thus $j$ divides $b$ and $c$.

Therefore, common divisors of $b$ and $c$ are the same as common divisors of $ac$ and $b$, in particular the greatest divisor is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gcd(ac,b)=d$.

Note that $d | ac$ and $d | b$.

If $\gcd(a,d) \not = 1$,

Let $\gcd(a,d) = k, k \not = 1$

then $k|a$ and $k|d|b$,
so $k | \gcd(a,b)$

but $\gcd(a,b)=1$, so $k|1$

$\therefore k=1$, so $ \unicode{x21af}$

So, $\gcd(a,d) = 1$

$\therefore d|c$

So, $d|\gcd(b,c)$

Meanwhile, $\gcd(b,c) | \gcd(ac,b)$

So, $\gcd(b,c) | d$

$\therefore \gcd(b,c) = d = \gcd(ac,b)$